# Passing a parameter to a called module

Tags: javascript, node.js

My `app.js` contains:

```
var m1 = require("./m1");
m1.f1(...);
```

My `m1.js` contains:

```
var m1 = module.exports = {};
m1.f1 = function(...) { };
```

I would like to pass `somevariable` when loading `m1` from `app.js`:

```
var m1 = require("./m1")(somevariable);
```

How can I write `m1.js` so that the function definition of `m1.f1` can access `somevariable`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to do this:

```
var m1 = require("./m1")(somevariable);            // it is equivalent to var m = require("./m1"); and then m(someVariable); so m (the exports of the module m1.js) should be a function
```

then `module.exports` in **m1.js** should be a function:

```
// m1.js:
module.exports = function(theVariable) {
    // use variable then return the following object:

    return {
        f1: function() { /* ... */ }
    };
}
```

So now you can use the module in **app.js** like this:

```
// app.js:
var m1 = require("./m1")(someVariable);

m1.f1(/* ... */);
```

`module.exports` is the value that will be returned by the call to `require` when loading the module.

Comment: I find that I could also export `somevariable` in `app.js` and require it from `m1.js`. Which approach is better?

Comment: I really don't know which approach is best as I don't know a lot about nodejs modules.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// app.js
require("./m1")(somevar);

// m1.js
module.exports = function(param) {
    return "something";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above by Ibrahim makes sense if you want to call m1 as a function. What it seems to me, though, is that your use case would be better served by using a JS class.

That way, you can import 'm1' the regular way with `require('m1')` and then create an instance of M1 with `new m1(<whatever you want to pass in>);`

Now when you want to call M1, just use `m1.f1()`

To support classes, your M1 should look something like:

```
export default class m1 {
 constructor(param1, param2) {
  this.param1 = param1;
  this.param2 = param2;
 }

 f1() {
  do whatever with params here
 }
}
```

The biggest benefit of this is readability. Now when someone (or you) looks at your code, they will see where this input is coming from. Otherwise, it can be hard to track down where the params are coming from. Especially as your code gets more complex.

Comment: If I have to `require('m1')` from more than one file, does this method cost more?